# No autoPlay or controls using media9 + VPlayer

Tags: media9

The effect I aim to produce can be witnessed by downloading and opening the PDF at the link below.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5s0xdpqyc8lfwvj/AABYk_I4dYXQk9gIiP1cn30Xa?dl=0

As you can see if you download it, clicking the orange 'film' icon opens a window for showing a video clip. But you must download it and run it locally for this to work since the legacy media (MOV) that it uses is now blocked in browsers for security reasons (that being one reason I'm turning to LaTeX).

The code below supplied by Alex Grahn has solved my earlier problem of needing a tiny icon that opens the video in a much larger window.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
    addresource=40631.mp4,
    windowed=640x480@tr,
    noplaybutton,
    activate=onclick,
    flashvars={source=40631.mp4&autoPlay=true}
  ]{\includegraphics[width=32px,height=32px]{filmicon32x32.png}} {VPlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

But some problems remain, and there are two (in effect, just one) that I will focus on in the current question:

(1) Currently, the autoPlay option does not work. One must click the video to get it to play. (I have the latest installation of texworks and media9.)

(2) If one opens the resulting PDF in Acrobat 9, it is impossible to add a skin for showing controls. One can select a skin in the Controls tab of the media properties dialog, but this has no effect.

These problems will reduce to one if I can solve problem (2), since I can live without autoPlay if the user can see the controls. Solving both (1) and (2) would be better, though.

These two problems also disappear if I use VideoPlayer.swf instead of VPlayer.swf. You can see the different results by downloading the two versions at the link below. The folder at that link also contains the orange film icon and the video clip used (which MediaInfo declares to be AVC).

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hy8m738l3tkpy96/AAAqCUbcMJLPcZXggM-M9QUza?dl=0

Unfortunately, simply switching to VideoPlayer.swf will not meet all my needs. I need VPlayer.swf since it is apparently a LaTeX 'in-house' product, which might therefore be tweaked to solve a different issue that I will address in another question.

Comment: (1) While the package file (`media9.sty`) you are using is up-to-date, the file `VPlayer.swf` embedded in the PDF is not. (I had a look into the PDF file I fetched from Dropbox.) Perhaps there is an old version of  `VPlayer.swf` in the current directory which gets embedded instead of the installed (right) one.

Comment: (2) `VPlayer.swf` is chromeless. That means, there are no skins you could use with it. The ones for VideoPayer.swf from Acrobat cannot be used with VPlayer. However, the whole video display of VPlayer acts as a Pause button. Cick it and keep the button pressed, the video pauses. Release the mouse button and the video resumes playing. If you release the mouse button only after moving the mouse out of the video, the video remains paused. Alternatively, VPlayer can be controlled (a) via the keyboard, (b) via mouse right click (context menu); for (b) add option `passcontext` to `\includemedia`.

Comment: @AlexG (1) Indeed there was an older copy of VPlayer.swf in the folder that I run texworks from (dated 6-14-2015, 514 KB). The copy in the texlive folder is dated 7-15-2015, 470 KB. However, when I remove the old copy and (presumably) use the newer one, I get the same behavior: autoPlay does not work. However, when I try VPlayer9 (only 215 KB), autoPlay **does** work. The great majority of references to the player in media9.pdf mention only VPlayer.swf; by my count, VPlayer**9**.swf is mentioned just 3 times.

Comment: @AlexG (2) Adding the passcontext parameter does show the context menu, but the only choices that seem to work are Play and Home. Moreover, as keyboard options, they work only *after* having been chosen once via the right-click menu. The "seek" choice is grayed out, whether or not "stepping" is specified among the Flash parameters. In fact, with stepping=true **nothing** works - not even Play- whether using VPlayer.swf or VPlayer9.swf.